# Participial phrase with a subject unomitted

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, idioms, subjects, participles

I wonder this sentence is both grammatically and idiomatically correct.
"That movie having a pretty big budget, filmmakers did not need to have one in order to succeed."

Comment: It's OK, but awkward. Try _With_ before _that movie_ to introduce the subordinate participial clause.

Comment: Semantically, the sentence is odd. What does it mean?

Comment: What does "one" refer to? The budget? Or some other element?